# Which component of Android does receive the google cloud messaging message

Tags: android

Google says: "GCM delivers messages as a broadcast. The receivers must be registered in the manifest in order to wake up the application."  but What component of Android does actually get the message first? Because İ dont think the Client app is the first component that gets the message by Broadcast receiver.

Would be happy if someone can explain it A bit more or give me A link to a source. Thx

Answer (score 2):

The client app is really the first component to get this broadcast by a broadcast receiver. Not only that, it is *the only* component to get it, simply because nobody else can listen for that specific broadcast (the one that is defined in your application's manifest).

But I guess you wanted to know who gets the message from the network and sends this broadcast. That is Google Play Services.